# There are invisible blue boxes on my artworks that I can't delete them in Illustrator CC 2018!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

EDIT: I figured out what happened. Somehow I got a jpg on my artboard and accidentally hide it. So they are not visible at all. They are duplicated every time I duplicated a artboard, so that's why my file size is so big. Still don't remember when did I got that jpg in.

---

[image: blue boxes show up when moving arboard.]

Somehow I got those blue boxes on my artwork. They are only visible when moving artboard. If I just selected the artworks themselves, the blue boxes won't show up. If I duplicate the artworks, the blue boxes are duplicated too. So they make my illustrator file really big. Does anyone have any idea of how to get rid off those blue boxes? Thanks!

[image: no blue boxes when selecting artwork.]

Comment: Are those guides? Can you clear them under the view menu?

Comment: Is this artwork you made yourself or is this a file you got somewhere else?

Comment: @Vincent I don't think it's made by the op. Those look and act from what he/she told us like clipping mask bounding boxes...

Comment: @Alin that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @Vincent It doesn't behave like anything else from AI that I know, only clipping masks act so confusing for those new to it. Well, if you feel like it, go ahead and add an answer. I can't write too much at the moment. Have a nice evening :D

Comment: Yup.. clipping masks, most likely due to gradient fills and then flattening (possibly).

Comment: I was working on a svg that someone else provide me. I didn't have this problem in the beginning, the blue boxes showed up about half through. I didn't use any guide or clipping masks. It looks like clipping masks, but if they are, I should be able to click into the masks, which I can't do that right now. @LateralTerminal's answer is the only workaround I can find now.

Comment: Color filled SVG type can do that at times. It generates raster image fills with vector clipping masks for some SVG files. Not certain why it does that, but I've seen it related to type in SVG files.

Comment: @Scott I'd upvote that if it were am answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are opening an SVG file from some unknown source....

Color filled SVG type can do that at times. It can generate raster image fills with vector clipping masks for some SVG files.

Not certain why it happens, but I've seen it related to type within some SVG files and how they are saved (or what may be saving them).

Removing them can be easy or difficult depending upon the actual file. I generally use the `Links` Panel to see if it's just a bunch of raster images. If so, the raster images can be selected and deleted via the `Links` Panel (you lose the fill colors). Then you generally have to release clipping masks and refill the "hollow" paths left behind with appropriate colors to match what the raster images were doing.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed this is a one color job.
For this particular instance, without knowing any additional information, you could possibly just go the menu bar and use Select->Same Fill Color. Then Cut and Paste it to another document.

If these are just guides that need to be cleared then try to unlock all your layers, then try Object-> Unlock all, and finally go to View-> Guides-> Clear Guides

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help. Selecting the same fill color and paste them into new document works for me now.

Comment: @lucky13820 Did clearing guides not work for you also? That's a solution that worked for me when when receiving other people's artwork.

Comment: No, they are not guide. But I figured out what happened. Somehow I got a jpg on my artboard and accidentally hide it.  So they are not visible at all. They are duplicated every time I duplicated a artboard, so that why my file size is so big.

Comment: @lucky13820 Oh, that make sense. Thanks for sharing I was really curious!